# Why does ssh-copy-id need verbose LogLevel to work in this case?

Tags: centos, ssh, key-authentication, ssh-config

I'm trying to set up public key authentication on a CentOS 7.3 guest, using WSL.

When trying to copy the public key using `ssh-copy-id`, it's rejected, saying it already exists on the VM. This is not the case, since it's a fresh install, and there isn't even an `.ssh` directory in `/root`.

After searching around, wrong file permissions seems to be a possible error, so I ran these commands:

**Guest**

```
chmod go-w ~
```

**Host**

```
chmod go-w ~
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/config
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

On the server in `sshd_config` public key authentication is enabled. The result of `ssh-copy-id` was the same.

However when I ran `ssh-copy-id -o "LogLevel VERBOSE" root@ip` it prompted me for the password, and then successfully copied over the key. After which I could use `ssh root@ip`, and successfully authenticate using my key.

`ssh` using password authentication worked the whole time.

Why didn't it work with normal `ssh-copy-id`, but it did using `ssh-copy-id -o "LogLevel VERBOSE"`?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Verbose` is not needed. `INFO` log level is enough, as it is already fixed in the [upstream repository](http://git.hands.com/?p=ssh-copy-id.git;a=blobdiff;f=ssh-copy-id;h=70d38662209c4dc4d5e2e710aed96ed86d16c2fe;hp=6a0447ae8628802e76cba4ddb79046c7d407d0e9;hb=35f05e39cda8670b3f6797330a3e521fda509a4c;hpb=baebbb9e18e4a1af7554d939710eacb665a24b68).

Commit message explains it pretty much:

> the LogLevel is set to 'None' we'll not get the
>   Permission Denied we're looking for.

This is not a problem in default configuration (since default value is `INFO` as per manual page). The problem occurs only if you set the `LogLevel=QUIET` in some of your configuration files (which is pretty much never what you want, unless you are sure that it the connection will succeed or you don't care if it does).

Comment: The LogLevel was set to QUIET in my .ssh/config file. Thank you, it works fine if I remove that line.